# How to create a Keras CNN model that allows me to classify three things using tensorflow VGG-16 Model on Google Colaboratory

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I see on `Tensorflow` (which is what I am using) that there are multiple ways to create such a program, however, everything I see does not show how to input the variables. How do I do that and where can I input these variables?

I will show what is the most recent thing I had been watching:
What I don't understand is how the epochs start working without any sort of input or data.

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input

base_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(224,224,3))
base_model.trainable = False

from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

model = models.Sequential([
    base_model,
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

history = model.fit(train_data,
                    validation_data = valid_data,
                    validation_steps = 16,
                    epochs = 30,
                    verbose=1,
                    callbacks = [es,model_cp])
```

Comment: Please understand, I am very new to all of this and would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Perhaps your code might be missing some declarations, it seems the callbacks haven't been defined, and for the `loss=tf..keras.losses.binary_crossentropy`, you'll have to `import tensorflow as tf`

Comment: You need to clarify the problem, the question is too vague, you mention variables, which variables? Also this code is incomplete and would not run. It is impossible to say anything without full code.

Answer (score 0):

The input to a `tensorflow.keras` model is set inside the `model.fit()` function call. Your code has a parameter `train_data`, which is supposed to be the training data to be supplied as input.
If you have sourced this code from somewhere else, you should look for the definitions for `train_data` and `valid_data` to know about what data is sent into the model. For a `tf.keras` model, the input data is either in the form of

1. Tensors (matrices), which are usually concatenated arrays of the
   entire collection of images that you have. This can be a `numpy.ndarray` or a `tf.Tensor` of shape `(number_of_images, 224, 224, 3)`
2. Generators, which iterate through a directory, and feed batches of images into the model while training. The number of images to be fed in one iteration is equal to the value of `batch_size` parameter.

The `train_data` in your code would most likely be a `numpy` array. You can either tweak the definition of the variable according to your requirements, or if you are unsure, you can use generators to feed the images directly from a directory. Here's an example of usage:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
    
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)  

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=train_dir,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True
)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=valid_dir,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True
)
```

To train your model, use:

```
model.fit(train_generator,
          validation generator),
          epochs = 30,
          verbose = 1)
```

The `train_dir` and `valid_dir` variables must be the path of your training and validation directories respectively.